# Uncaught ReferenceError: teste is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Ionic 5)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I am developing an app using the Ionic 5 framework. I created a button that should perform a function where the period is increased by `+1` whenever the button is pressed.

projeto completo pode ser acessado no Github: https://github.com/paulojoy/scoreboard_/tree/master/src/app/folder

folder.page.html e folder.page.ts

My Html looks like this:

```
   <!-- Fouls and Period -->
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <div class="title_period">PERIODO</div>
      <button id="botao" onclick="teste()">teste</button>
      <div id="period">
        <p class="period">0</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>


//E esse é a função em javascript://



//Esse é o trecho do código que deveria ser executado sempre que o botão fosse clicado//


  function teste () {
  
  var x = document.querySelector('.period').textContent;
  var y = Number(x);
    if (y <= 4){
      y ++;
    }
      else {
        y = 0;
      }

      document.querySelector('.period').textContent = String(y);
  
}
```

Comment: So it is saying it can not find the function. hard for us to know why it is not in global scope with what you provided.

Comment: If that function is defined outside of your @Component class, you will not be able to access it in the template.  Please post your full component class.  Also, you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM directly, let Angular do it by setting a template variable and updating that in your component.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using `(click)` instead of `onclick` in Angular per the docs? [User Input](https://angular.io/guide/user-input). The error in your code is with Angular, not Ionic. When I write Ionic I do use `ion-button`, but that is not causing your issue.

Change button to:

```
      <button id="botao" (click)="teste()">teste</button>
```

Here is a similar post. [How to fix Uncaught ReferenceError: play is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298199/how-to-fix-uncaught-referenceerror-play-is-not-defined-at-htmlbuttonelement-onc)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best way to use the ionic framework 5 is to use the button component already available:

```
<ion-button color="primary">Primary</ion-button>
```

In the documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button) you can see other ways to use it.

For click function calls, we usually use event click:

```
<ion-button (click)="teste()" color="primary">Primary</ion-button>
```

In your .TS file you don't need to put "function" in functions. You can put just test () {}, of course, outside the constructor but within the page class.